# Why are so many correct solutions found?

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have a list of "base atoms" and a longer atom made up only of those base atoms. repeats are allowed. I whipped up the following code to generate lists of all the atoms which could possibly make up the longer atom. This code seems to work with the exception that it finds many repeats of the same (correct) solutions and I am not sure why?

```
basics([a, abc, def, aaa]).
  
candidate(aaaabcaaadef).

join_atoms(Atoms, Atom):- join_atoms( Atoms, '', Atom ) .
 
join_atoms( [],    Atom,      Atom ) . 
join_atoms( [H|T], AtomAccum, Atom ) :- 
    atom_concat( AtomAccum, H, UpdatedAtom) ,
    join_atoms( T, UpdatedAtom, Atom ) . 

split_atoms( C, Atoms ):- split_atoms( C, [], Atoms ) .

split_atoms( '', AtomsAccum, Atoms ) :-
    candidate(C) ,
    reverse( AtomsAccum, AtomsAccumR ) ,
    join_atoms( AtomsAccumR, C ) ,
    Atoms = AtomsAccumR .
split_atoms(C, AtomsAccum, Atoms):- 
    basics( B ) ,
    member( SubAtom, B ) ,
    sub_atom( C, _, Length, _, SubAtom ) , 
    sub_atom( C, Length, _, 0, AtomRest ) , 
    split_atoms(AtomRest, [SubAtom|AtomsAccum], Atoms).  

main:-
    candidate( C ) ,
    findall( Atoms, split_atoms(C, Atoms), AllAtoms ) ,
    sort( AllAtoms, UniqueAtoms ) , 
    write(UniqueAtoms),
    nl .
```

The `findall/3` and `sort/2` will get all solutions and remove the duplicates, of course. But without those the correct solutions are repeated multiple times.

For example (output truncated)

```
| ?- split_atoms(aaaabcaaadef, Atoms).

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def] ? a

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,aaa,def]

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]

Atoms = [a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]

.
.
.
```

Can anyone suggest why this is happening? Presumably it is backtracking more than necessary for some reason? Or perhaps my code is unintentionally creating a situation which can be minimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are over-thinking the problem here.

To paraphrase your problem statement:

> I want find all the different, distinct ways a given symbol can be composed from an alphabet of shorter symbols.

To solve that requires a couple of observations:

- The longer symbol must have as a prefix one of the shorter symbols contained in the alphabet
- The above recursively holds true if you strip such a prefix off the longer symbol

That leads to this simple solution: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/tLTQiVNQ.pl

[[`sub_atom/5`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sub_atom/5) is an ISO-standard built-in predicate that lets you disassemble atoms by offset and length]

```
% --------------------------------------
% compose( Atom, Subatoms, Composition )
% --------------------------------------
compose( ''   , _        , []     ) .  % the empty set composes the empty atom
compose( Atom , Subatoms , [A|As] ) :- % otherwise...
  member(A,Subatoms) ,                 % - fish a symbol out of our alphabet
  sub_atom(Atom,0,L,P,A) ,             % - see if its a prefix of our candidate
  sub_atom(Atom,L,P,_,Nextatom) ,      % - get the next atom (the suffix)
  compose(Nextatom, Subatoms,As)       % - and recurse down
  .                                    % Easy!
```

Given your sample data:

```
?- compose( aaaabcaaadef, [a,abc,def,aaa], Xs).
```

The following results are produced on backtracking:

```
Xs = [a, a, a, abc, a, a, a, def]
Xs = [a, a, a, abc, aaa, def]
Xs = [aaa, abc, a, a, a, def]
Xs = [aaa, abc, aaa, def]
false
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Looking back at the code I quickly wrote it is definitely completely redundant to rejoin the subatoms. With a proper base case to terminate the recursion as done with `compose/3` this is indeed a much easier problem.

Comment: Changed 'letter' to 'symbol' for you. Better?

Answer (score 3):

> Why are so many correct solutions found?

Not so fast! Let's start with a related question:

> Why are so many incorrect solutions almost found?

To answer that question, let me modify your program by negating one single goal:

```
split_atoms( '', AtomsAccum, Atoms ) :-
    candidate(C) ,
    reverse( AtomsAccum, AtomsAccumR ) ,
    \+ join_atoms( AtomsAccumR, C ) ,   % <=== negated
    Atoms = AtomsAccumR .
split_atoms(C, AtomsAccum, Atoms):- 
    basics( B ) ,
    member( SubAtom, B ) ,
    sub_atom( C, _, Length, _, SubAtom ) , 
    sub_atom( C, Length, _, 0, AtomRest ) , 
    split_atoms(AtomRest, [SubAtom|AtomsAccum], Atoms).

?- split_atoms(aaaabcaaadef, Atoms).
   Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,def,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,aaa,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,def]
;  Atoms = [a,a,a,a,a,a,def,def]
;  ... .
```

So now, we are looking at near-solutions that your program will have to consider and only filter out in the very last moment. That does not look very right, does it? So your program considers much too many candidates only to weed them out anyway.

What you need is some **specialization** of your program. Often (as in this case) it suffices to add some further goals:

```
... .
split_atoms(C, AtomsAccum, Atoms):-
    basics( B ) ,
    member( SubAtom, B ) ,
    Before = 0,                        % specialization
    sub_atom( C, Before, Length, _, SubAtom ) , 
    sub_atom( C, Length, _, 0, AtomRest ) , 
    split_atoms(AtomRest, [SubAtom|AtomsAccum], Atoms).
```

And now, there are no longer any near-solutions.

Even better you can replace this by:

```
... .
split_atoms(C, AtomsAccum, Atoms):-
    basics( B ) ,
    member( SubAtom, B ) ,
    atom_concat(SubAtom, AtomRest, C),
    split_atoms(AtomRest, [SubAtom|AtomsAccum], Atoms).
```

And even more so, you can remove `basics/1` and `candidate/1` as has been suggested by @NicholasCarey.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using DCG:

```
split_atom(Atom, Atoms) :-
    atom_chars(Atom, Chars),
    phrase(list_of_atoms(Atoms), Chars).

list_of_atoms([A|As]) --> basic_atom(A), list_of_atoms(As).
list_of_atoms([])     --> \+ [_].

basic_atom(a)   --> [a].
basic_atom(aaa) --> [a,a,a].
basic_atom(abc) --> [a,b,c].
basic_atom(def) --> [d,e,f].
```

Example:

```
?- time(forall(split_atom(aaaabcaaadef, Atoms), writeln(Atoms))).

[a,a,a,abc,a,a,a,def]
[a,a,a,abc,aaa,def]
[aaa,abc,a,a,a,def]
[aaa,abc,aaa,def]

% 60 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.016 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)

true.
```

Comment: What does `\+ [_]` serve for what `[]` does not?

Comment: @false With `\+ [_]` query `?- phrase(list_of_atoms(Atoms), [a,a,b,c,d], R).` fails. However, with `[]`, that query succeeds (although `d` is not a basic atom).

Comment: So you make a generalization fail.

Comment: @false What I've actually done is to ensure that the predicate fails with input data that don't represent lists composed of just basic atoms.

Comment: With `[]` you would have a much purer solution...